# A Fruitful Riddle

Tags: riddle

> I am warm and fuzzy, but I have a stone heart.
>   I taste very good, just put me in your cart.
>   As an adjective, I'm nice and fair,
>   but if you're in the forest, I am tasty to a bear.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are...

> A peach!
>
> It's warm and fuzzy, but has a hard seed
>  It tastes good, and you can buy it at a store
>  "Peachy" is an adjective similar to nice and fair

Am I right?

Comment: Good job... that was quick! I will accept your answer, but it says I have to wait 6 mins.

Comment: Cool :D Alright :D

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you might be

> **a Peach**
>
> Peaches are fuzzy, but have a peach stone in their middle.
>  They are tasty and can be bought in the supermarket (in season).
>  People say ["you're a peach"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=you%27re%20a%20peach) to compliment someone on their niceness.
>  And [bears like them](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=REZfOgMCmms).